# how Disable rerendrig after change useState?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this code, after call setStopChange function my component is rerendring, why, and how it fix?
To detect rerender i use chrome react profiler

```
import s from './Pizza.module.scss';
 
const Pizza = () => {
    const [stopChange, setStopChange] = useState(false);
 
    console.log('rerender');
 
    return (
        <>
            <div
                className={s.wrapper}
                onMouseEnter={() => setStopChange(true)}
                onMouseLeave={() => setStopChange(false)}
            >
                <div className={s.container}>
                </div>
            </div>
 
            <div className={s.box}>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
 
export default Pizza;
```

if i set onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave empty functions, i don`t have this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question is not very clear but if you are asking why component rerenders two times, it is because of strictmode in index.js file. You can remove it for **testing purpose** and you will see component rerenders only one time.

Comment: Component rerendring every time when i  use function setStopChange

Comment: Component rerenders every time setFunction runs. This is the expected behavior. If you don't want the component to rerender on onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave and just want to store the value, you should use ref instead